# regex use with newlines and spaces

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a text file I'm reading with a `C#` program and am needing to split it's contents.  I decided to use `Regex.Split()`.

The pattern I am trying to look for is `\n( )+Copyright`

here's an example of the text:

> \r\n\r\nLANGUAGE: ENGLISH\r\n\r\nDISTRIBUTION: Every Zone\r\n\r\nPUBLICATION-TYPE: Newspaper\r\n\r\n\r\n     Copyright 2014 Washingtonpost.Newsweek Interactive Company, LLC d/b/a\r\n                            Washington Post Digital\r\n                              All Rights Reserved\r\n"

the reason for the newline being included is because I also have instances where the word copyright shows up in a paragraph:

> \r\n\r\nFrom Blood Aces by Doug Swanson, to be published by Viking, a member of Penguin\r\nGroup (USA) LLC on Aug. 14, 2014. Copyright © 2014 by Doug J. Swanson.\r\n

however the problem i have is when I perform this call:

`var splitContent= Regex.Split(filecontent, @"\n( )+Copyright");`

i get over 2x as many items in `splitContent` as there should be.  I've tried modifying the regex pattern to `@"(\n){1}?( )+Copyright"` and a few other similar type patterns I get 4-5x the number of items in `splitContent` I should be getting.

Is this the correct way to be performing this kind of regex?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you enclose space in parentheses? Any captured group also putted in result array.

Comment: I put it in parentheses to better visually identify the space...I wasn't aware that it would also put that in the array

Comment: @PetSerAl  Thank you! I just removed the parentheses and it worked exactly the way I needed it to.  Thank you for making me aware of captured groups also being added to the result array!

Comment: Any reason you don't just use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: What do you *expect* the result to be? Show us some sample text, the expected result, and what you're actually getting.

Comment: @PetSerAl  If you set your comment as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If capturing parentheses are used in a `Regex.Split` expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array. For example, if you split the string "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within capturing parentheses, the returned array includes a string element that contains the hyphen.
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
>
> public class Example
> {
>    public static void Main()
>    {
>       string input = "plum-pear";
>       string pattern = "(-)";
>
>       string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);    // Split on hyphens 
>       foreach (string match in substrings)
>       {
>          Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
>       }
>    }
> }
> // The example displays the following output:
> //    'plum'
> //    '-'
> //    'pear'
> ```
>
> [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8yttk7sy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why try to reinvent the wheel? Just change your regular expression to use the correct options:

```
RegexOptions options     = RegexOptions.Multiline
                         | RegexOptions.Ignorecase
                         ;
Regex        rxCopyright = new Regex( "^\s*Copyright", options );

string[]     lines       = rxCopyright.Split( yourStringHere ) ;
```

`RegexOptions.Multiline` tells the regular expression engine to

> Use multiline mode, where `^` and `$` match the beginning and end
>   of each line (instead of the beginning and end of the input string).
>   For more information, see [Multiline Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Multiline).

So your corpus of text will be split into blocks using the word `copyright` if at the beginning of any line (with or without leading whitespace).

And if you want to use parentheses for clarity, add `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` to the mix. It

> Specifies that the only valid captures are explicitly named or numbered
>   groups of the form `(?<name>…)`. This allows unnamed parentheses to act as noncapturing groups without the syntactic clumsiness of the expression `(?:…)`.